# Work done on rigid body vs particle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, rigid-body-dynamics

I know that the basic definition of the work done on a particle is: $$W_{12}=\int_1^2\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$
but what if I have want to calculate the work done on a rigid body? is the formula the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rigid body, in addition to translation, can also rotate. However, rotation isn't possible in the case of a point particle. So when we calculate the work done on a rigid body, we also need to account for the work done by the [torque](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) acting on it, in addition to the work done by the force. Thus the general expression for a work done on a rigid body by a force $\mathbf F$ and a torque $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ is

$$W=\underbrace{\int \mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d \mathbf r}_{\text{work done by the force}}+\underbrace{\int \boldsymbol{\tau}\cdot \mathrm d \boldsymbol{\theta}}_{\text{work done by the torque}}$$

where $\mathbf r$ is the position vector of the rigid body's center of mass and $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is the angle rotated by the body.

Comment: Are $\mathrm{F}$ and $\mathrm{\tau}$ the  net force and net torque?

Comment: @herosai Yes, $F$ and $\tau$ are the net force and net torque respectively. Also, see my edit.

Comment: I think $\mathbf{r}$ should be the position vector of the center of mass.

Comment: But in case of rigid body how the energy that is transferred through work done on a particle of the body (the force acts at a point of the rigid body) translates into energy of the whole system?