# Should the work done on a rigid body be calculated with respect to the point of application, or the center of mass?

Tags: classical-mechanics, work

I'm trying to understand work calculation for a force acting on a rigid body (as opposed to a point particle).

My understanding is that the same basic principle applies: the work done by force F on body B is the line integral of F over the curve C which was travelled by some point P.

My question is, which point is P? Do we integrate over the curve travelled by the point which the force is acting upon at a given moment (if so, what if this point changes over time)? Or do we integrate over the curve travelled by the center of mass of the object?

I have looked online and found different resources which seem to suggest both approaches respectively. For example: [Work done on rigid body vs particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557754/work-done-on-rigid-body-vs-particle) Here the latter is mentioned, and elsewhere the former approach is mentioned. Please explain the simplest or best strategy for such problems.

Clarification:

I'm mainly looking to understand how to calculate the work done by a specific force. I understand that that total work will then be the sum of all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example: [Work done on rigid body vs particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557754/work-done-on-rigid-body-vs-particle) Here the latter is mentioned, and elsewhere the former approach is mentioned.

In user258881's answer to the linked question there are two terms:

> $$W=\underbrace{\int \mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d \mathbf r}_{\text{work done by the force}}+\underbrace{\int \boldsymbol{\tau}\cdot \mathrm d \boldsymbol{\theta}}_{\text{work done by the torque}}$$

The "work done by the force" isn't well-named. This term accounts for the work that goes into increasing the translational kinetic energy of the body. But it doesn't really account for all the work done by the applied force. It only accounts for the component of the force that acts through the center of mass.

The "work done by the torque" accounts for the work that goes into increasing the rotational kinetic energy of the body. This accounts for the component of force acting perpendicular to the vector between the point of application and the center of mass.

If you sum these up, you get the total work done by the force. This is the same as your first method of integrating over the curve travelled by the point of application of the force.

The issue is that "the force" and "the torque", as named by user258881, aren't two separate things. In your conceptualization of the problem, they are both components of the applied force. The main difference is that you are imagining a floating in body in space with only one force acting on it, so you can identify "the point of application of the force" as a single point. User258881 was considering a body acted on by multiple forces, so there is no single "point of application" and it is more convenient to first separate each force into translational component and torque component, and sum them up separately before integrating to find the total work done.

Comment: Yup - you can do a lot of work on a flywheel (or have it do work) and you really really really hope that the center of mass is not translating...

Comment: Thank you. Let me clarify my question: Suppose indeed there are multiple forces acting on the object: F1, F2, F3. Suppose I calculate the torque for each one, and then integrate each one with respect the the angle, and get the work that goes into the rotational kinetic energy. Now, I would like to figure out the work applied by each individual force, that goes into, like, "regular translation" (like we have with point particles, before all this stuff became really complicated). So how do I compute the work done on the object specifically by say, F2? Which is applied somewhere on the body.

Comment: You can find the work done by F2 by integrating over the path of the point of application, but you can't be sure that all that work is done on the body --- some of it might be transferred to be done on the sources of the other forces.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. Is there a standard way to calculate the work done specifically by F2 when dealing with rigid bodies? Do people usually do that? Or do we usually just calculate the net force, the net torque, and then integrate along the curve followed by the center mass, as detailed by user258881?

Comment: @AvivCohn, As far as I know you can identify the work done by each force, and the total work done on the body, but if there are multiple forces working I don't think you can identify how much of the work done on the body comes from each force --- but maybe someone with a better mechanics background than me will correct me.